# What is the reason for a TypeError in my Python code?

Tags: python

Here is the actual code

```
age = input('How old are you? ')

# 2-8 2 dollar ticket
# 65 5 dollar ticket
# 10 dollar for everyone else
if not ((age >= 2 and age <= 8) or age >= 65):
    print('You are not a child, you pay full price')
else:
    print('You are paying a discounted price')
```

Just learning to code but I did something similar and had the same code error, then I copied the one from the online course I am taking and got the same error.

Comment: `input()` returns the input as a `string`. you need to convert it to integer object, `int(string, conversion_base)`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow ! As a general rule on Stack Overflow, the title of your question should summarize your specific problem. This website mostly works on upvotes and downvotes. The community is pretty strict about the rules to ensure a certain quality of the content. If you don't follow them, you might expect a downvotes raining on you, which can be overwhelming at first :-) Read more on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to compare a string with an integer. You need to convert the string to an integer first:

```
age = int(input('How old are you? '))
```

To make sure the user inputs an integer, you can use this.

```
age = input('How old are you? ')
while not age.isdigit():
    age = input('Enter an integer. How old are you? ')
age = int(age)
```

Answer (score 1):

when convertin to `int` object, `exceptions` may be raised by the program so use the try except (if you need to print some message before exiting the program).

```
age = input('How old are you? ')
try:
  age=int(age)
except ValueError:
  print('only numbers is alowed! please re run the program')
  raise

# 2-8 2 dollar ticket
# 65 5 dollar ticket
# 10 dollar for everyone else
if not ((age >= 2 and age <= 8) or age >= 65):
    print('You are not a child, you pay full price')
else:
    print('You are paying a discounted price')
```